# Dotfuscator Invalid serial key

Tags: windows, dotfuscator, preemptive

I ran set up files for Dotfuscator Professional Edition 3.0. after running setup it takes input from user to complete registration. Then after completing  registation it asks user for serial number. i mistakenly input the wrong serial number. if i open it now it gives me following error.

```
Invalid Dotfuscator Serial Number. Please contact your vendor
```

after clicking Ok it closes the application. i tried re-installing software (in hope that it will ask me for serial key again) but picking already entered wrong serial numbers. i also had tried deleting old registry values. 
I dont want to format my machine right now to complete its removal and this software is must.if i again install windows it will eat up my whole day with all softwares. 
can anybody suggest something. i want this to completely install and then install and activate it with correct serial number.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to correct this by deleting your "Dotfuscator.dat" file, which is located in 
"C:\ProgramData\PreEmptive Solutions\Dotfuscator Professional Edition\3.0" (or the equivalent for your operating system).

Comment: i am unable to find this file. this was not present in my installation folder

Comment: Note that Dotfuscator.dat is in the program data directory, not in the program files directory.